# Retrieving data based on rule in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to retrieve data from a Realtime Database in Firebase based on logged in user.

My nodes in Firebase look like this: https://prnt.sc/kpdoq9
and my rules are set up like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userhours": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to retrieve the data through my method:

```
  loadUserHours() {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref("userhours")
        .once("value")
        .then((data) => {
            const obj = data.val();
            console.log(obj)
            })
        },
```

I get an `Error: permission_denied at /userhours`

I think it has to do with rules

```
".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
```

Because the "main inner node" is not the actual uid (logged in user id), but a random key generated by Firebase? What should my structure look like?

I assume that the rule is looking for a uid in the path `userhours/{uidhere}/..` when the firebase node is set up like `userhours/{randomKeyGeneratedByFirebase}/..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database security rules don't filter data for you. Instead, it only checks whether a listener is allowed access to the data when you attach it.

When a user attaches a listener to `/userhours`, the Firebase Database server checks if they have read permission to that node. Since you only grant read permission on `/userhours/$uid`, nobody has read permission on `/userhours` and the read is rejected.

You'll want to attach the listener to `/userhours/$uid` instead. So:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("userhours")
  .child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .once("value")
  .then((data) => {
      const obj = data.val();
      console.log(obj)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank. I'm faced with another issue now however, if I have `".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"` and `".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",`
Set up like this, it's all fine, but if I do have ".read": "true", Firebase will fetch all nodes which is messing up my array that I'm using for updating the current users node. How can I make sure that even though I set read access to everyone, that only the specific user's node gets updated?

Comment: Sorry If I'm being a bit abstract, it's hard sketching everything out in the comments section. Basically, I'm trying to build a time-tracker app where users log their hours (here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vhfmjpy/) 

Users put their hours in --> gets stored in an array --> push to firebase to logged in user's node --> How can I now retrieve only this specific node? Firebase is messing me up by assigning an index to each node..

Comment: The code in my answer reads only data from the node of the user that is logged in. It works with the rules you shared in your question.

Comment: Yeah, so far so good, but when I push new data to firebase, and then try to retrieve it, i'll have to do different methods for fetching the data based on logged in user. Say I have an admin with the rule 

`".read": "root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)",`
If I now wish to retrieve data from the `userhours`, logged in as admin, I'll get back an array with each node, so my `snapshot.val()` needs to be adjusted, whereas if I'm logged in with a user that can only see his/her own node, I just get an object back. Is there any chance I can pm you? It's kinda hard to explain, sorry about that..